# When price rule is triggered, Target Customer Amount and additional discount $ stop working

Tags: cpq

So I have a price rule that gives a 15% discount if the order is paid upfront.

Price Actions:

```
SBQQ__RegularPrice__c = SBQQ__ProratedListPrice__c * .85

SBQQ__CustomerPrice__c= IF(SBQQ__Discount__c = NULL, (SBQQ__ProratedListPrice__c) * (.85 - 0), (SBQQ__ProratedListPrice__c) * (.85 - SBQQ__Discount__c))

SBQQ__NetPrice__c = IF(SBQQ__Discount__c = NULL, (SBQQ__ProratedListPrice__c) * (.85 - 0), (SBQQ__ProratedListPrice__c) * (.85 - SBQQ__Discount__c))
```

I have a suspician it's because the formula above isn't taking into account the addition discount $ field (SBQQ__AdditionalDiscountAmount__c) but I'm having a hard time how to take into account both additional discount fields (or if this is even the right train of thought.)

Comment: in your price rules, where did you specify the additional discount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I think it may resolve your question.